# Is it possible in RubyMine to run standardrb in a single file with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: rubymine

I want to replace the keyboard shortcut for formatting a file with calling `standardrb --fix` on that file. Is there a way to do that in RubyMine?

Comment: You can try creating an external tool for that purpose: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/configuring-third-party-tools.html